# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined in React native web app

Tags: firebase, react-native, webpack, react-native-web

I am working on React native web app. I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` error after running my project

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at ./node_modules/idb/build/index.js (index.cjs:21:20)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/index.cjs.js (index.js:3:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./node_modules/firebase/app/dist/index.cjs.js (index.js:17:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/firebase.js (firebase.js:1:1)
```

I am adding `firebase.js` and `webpack.config.js` codes for reference.

**firebase.js**

```
import {initializeApp} from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging } from "firebase/messaging";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = getMessaging(app);

export { messaging }
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const appDirectory = path.resolve(__dirname, '../');

const babelLoaderConfiguration = {
  test: /\.(js)|(jsx)|(ts)|(tsx)$/,
  // Add every directory that needs to be compiled by Babel during the build.
  include: [
    path.resolve(appDirectory, 'index.web.js'), // Entry to your application
    path.resolve(appDirectory, 'App.tsx'), // Change this to your main App file
    path.resolve(appDirectory, 'src'),
    path.resolve(appDirectory, 'component'),
    path.resolve(appDirectory, 'node_modules/react-native-uncompiled'),
    path.resolve(appDirectory, 'node_modules/react-native-paper'),
  ],
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      cacheDirectory: true,
      // The 'metro-react-native-babel-preset' preset is recommended to match React Native's packager
      presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
      // Re-write paths to import only the modules needed by the app
      plugins: [
        'react-native-web',
        [
          'module-resolver',
          {
            alias: {
              '^react-native$': 'react-native-web',
            },
          },
        ],
      ],
    },
  },
};

// This is needed for webpack to import static images in JavaScript files.
const imageLoaderConfiguration = {
  test: /\.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg)$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[name].[ext]',
      esModule: false,
    },
  },
};

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    path.resolve(appDirectory, 'index.web.tsx'),
  ],

  // configures where the build ends up
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.web.js',
    path: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'dist'),
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      babelLoaderConfiguration,
      imageLoaderConfiguration,
      {
        test: /\.ttf$/,
        loader: 'url-loader', // or directly file-loader
        include: path.resolve(
          __dirname,
          'node_modules/react-native-vector-icons',
        ),
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude:
          /node_modules\/(?!(react-native-elements|react-native-vector-icons)\/).*/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
    ],
  },

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'react-native$': 'react-native-web',
    },
    extensions: ['.web.js', '.web.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
  },
};
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you solve the issue?