# ReferenceError: require is not defined when using Firebase SDK in React Native Web with Webpack

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, webpack

I am working on a React Native Web project using Nx, and I have set up a custom Webpack configuration to export React Native Web. Everything seems to be working fine until I try to install the Firebase SDK JavaScript package. When I import Firebase in my code, I encounter the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    <anonymous> webpack://MY_PROJECT_NAME/source/./node_modules/@firebase/app/node_modules/idb/build/index.js?:2
```

I have checked my Webpack configuration, and it appears to be correctly set up to handle CommonJS-style modules. Here's my Webpack configuration:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin = require('@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin');

const appDirectory = path.resolve(__dirname, '../');

const babelConfig = require(path.resolve(appDirectory, 'babel.config'));

// Babel loader configuration
const babelLoaderConfiguration = {
    test: /\.(tsx|jsx|ts|js|cjs)?$/,
    exclude: [
        {
            and: [
                // babel will exclude these from transpiling
                path.resolve(appDirectory, '../node_modules'),
                path.resolve(appDirectory, 'ios'),
                path.resolve(appDirectory, 'android'),
            ],
            // whitelisted modules to be transpiled by babel
            not: [],
        },
    ],
    use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
            cacheDirectory: true,
            // Presets and plugins imported from main babel.config.js in root dir
            presets: babelConfig.presets,
            plugins: ['react-native-web', ...(babelConfig.plugins || [])],
        },
    },
};

// Image loader configuration
const imageLoaderConfiguration = {
    test: /\.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg)$/,
    use: {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            esModule: false,
        },
    },
};

// File loader configuration
const fileLoaderConfiguration = {
    test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                name: '[name].[ext]',
                outputPath: 'fonts/',
            },
        },
    ],
};

module.exports = (argv) => {
    return {
        devServer: {
            port: 8080,
            static: [{directory: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'web/public')}],
        },
        entry: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'src', 'main'),
        output: {
            clean: true,
            path: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'web/dist'),
            filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
            sourceMapFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].map',
            chunkFilename: '[id].[chunkhash].js',
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [
                '.web.js',
                '.js',
                '.web.ts',
                '.ts',
                '.web.jsx',
                '.jsx',
                '.web.tsx',
                '.tsx',
                '.cjs',
            ],
            alias: {
                'react-native$': 'react-native-web',
                '@herlife/theme': path.resolve(
                    appDirectory,
                    '../libs/theme/src/index.ts',
                ),
                '@herlife/crashlytics': path.resolve(
                    appDirectory,
                    '../libs/crashlytics/src/index.tsx',
                ),
                '@herlife/types': path.resolve(
                    appDirectory,
                    '../libs/types/src/index.ts',
                ),
                '@herlife/constants': path.resolve(
                    appDirectory,
                    '../libs/constants/src/index.ts',
                ),
                '@herlife/analytics': path.resolve(
                    appDirectory,
                    '../libs/analytics/src/index.ts',
                ),
                '@herlife/firebase': path.resolve(
                    appDirectory,
                    '../libs/firebase/src/index.ts',
                ),
            },
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                babelLoaderConfiguration,
                imageLoaderConfiguration,
                fileLoaderConfiguration,
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
            // Fast refresh plugin
            new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin(),

            // Plugin that takes public/index.html and injects script tags with the built bundles
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'web/public/index.html'),
            }),

            // Defines __DEV__ and process.env as not being null
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                __DEV__: argv.mode !== 'production' || true,
                process: {env: {}},
            }),

            new CopyWebpackPlugin({
                patterns: [
                    {
                        from: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'web/public') + '/**/!(*.html)',
                        to() {
                            return path.resolve(appDirectory, 'web/dist') + '/[name][ext]';
                        },
                    },
                ],
            }),
        ],
        optimization: {
            // Split into vendor and main js files
            splitChunks: {
                cacheGroups: {
                    commons: {
                        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                        name: 'vendor',
                        chunks: 'initial',
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    };
};
```

**Usage:**

`import {} from 'firebase/analytics';`

Has anyone encountered a similar problem or have any insights into what might be causing this error when using Firebase in a React Native Web project with a custom Webpack configuration?

Comment: None of this code seems to be importing Firebase, can you should the [mcve] code that actually [goes wrong](/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I just imported `import {} from '@firebase/analytics';` and got the error.

Comment: that looks like invalid syntax, imports are either `import { namedthing} from "library.js"` or `import "library.js"`. What happens if you just use the latter?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans same issue is remaining

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I found another relative issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75516772/uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined-in-react-native-web-app):

Comment: I think we need to back up just a moment: _when_ do you get this error? _during_ building, or if you try to _use_ your successfully built bundle? And if it's the first, create that [mcve] (read the article that links to for help on how to do that, but it's _really_ important to do, even moreso for yourself than for your post: reducing your code is how you almost always get the information you need to solve the problem yourself, so most of the after running through the MCVE exercise you don't even need to post anymore, or you figured it out and can write an answer to your own question)